# RTMPS and self signed certificate

Tags: flash, video.js, self-signed, rtmps

I'm developing the **RTMPS** live streaming by **videojs**. (**Flash player**)

RTMPS server with public certificate is played when accessing web domain.

*ex) rtmps://www.example.com:5555/live/ (Success)*

But,

I want to use RTMPS server with self-signed certificate and IP address. 
(IP keeps changing.)

*ex) rtmps://123.456.78.9:5555/live/ (Failed)*

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki/RTMPS), "To use self-signed certificates you have to accept the certificate on the client, inserting it into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store."

However, it may be a better solution to create a dynamic DNS hostname. Many services offer this for free and it's a simple process; Google dynamic DNS hostname.

Once you have that, you should be able to create a certificate using a recognized service. LetsEncrypt offers certificates for free. See [this note](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/dyndns-no-ip-managed-dns-support/883/5) on using dynamic providers with LetsEncrypt.